# Android: how to define layout for custom View in xml?

Tags: android

I would like to create a class MyView, which extends LinearLayout.  MyView has a fairly complex View hierarchy, with a number of children which have children, etc.  I would like to define this hierarchy in Xml.  However, I would also like MyView to be reusable in code.  I would like MyView to be instantiated with its complex hierarchy without creating or modifying any additional Xml files; I would like some other LinearLayout to be able to do something like:

```
MyView view = new MyView(linearLayout.getContext());
linearLayout.addView(view);
```

This could be accomplished by setting up the View hierarchy in java code in the constructor of MyView.  But it seems like I should be able to use a xml layout to do this in the constructor.  I guess basically I am looking for the equivalent of Activity.setContentView(...) for a View; but can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your MyView class extends LinearLayout, you can just do this in the constructor:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.myviewlayout, this);
```